# why my bootstrap carousel is not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

the carousel shows me the first image that's it , it is  like the slider is bloked, the buttons not working either

```html
<main>
  <div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-mdb-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" >
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="images/hero1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Wild Landscape">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item ">
        <img src="images/hero2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Camera">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item ">
        <img src="images/hero3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Exotic Fruits">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-mdb-target="#slider" data-mdb-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-mdb-target="#slider" data-mdb-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</main>


    
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remember you need to load jQuery, bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js for it to work and then call the function. See here for more: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#via-javascript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attention to the bootstrap version used.
In version 5.2 for example you need to use as:

> data-bs-ride
>  data-bs-target
>  data-bs-slide

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<main>
      <div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" >
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="images/hero1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Wild Landscape">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="images/hero2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Camera">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="images/hero3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="Exotic Fruits">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#slider" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
</main>
```

Hope this helps.